# Visual studio not hitting the breakpoint for xamarin.forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im facing this issue from the time I have updated my VS , I have created the test project and its working fine in other projects but its not working in my current project.
I tried deleting .bin and .obj files its the same again . I even tried this "project property window and go to "Build->Advanced" to check if "Debugging inforamtion" is "Portable"" and even this is portable in my project.
Please share me if u have any solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration of your project if `Use Fast Deployment` is enabled, if not enable it and try again .

[image]

Refer to

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-not-hit-debugging-xamarin-android-proje/1561025